# Acrobat: Select and adjust single elements

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Is it possible to select a single element of a PDF and change its color with Acrobat Pro?

I've used Pitstop, which provides a great range of possibilities. But where isn't it needed and Acrobat itself is enough?

Comment: I fail to see how you can't just use Pitstop. What exactly are you trying to achieve? The workflow would certainly be faster to just use Pitstop.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor for example on machines where Pitstop isn't installed. I'm searching for ways with Acrobat itself instead of using this Plugin.

It's not only about changing colors of elements, but also coordinates, width, height etc.

Comment: Yeah Acrobat can't really do anything close to that. What it can do is highly imprecise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrobat, to the best of my knowledge, does not have features such as a color/swatch panel, a pen tool, direct selection tool, etc. So editing *objects* is not really a primary focus. You can often use the `Edit Object` feature in Acrobat. However, that will merely open the object in an appropriate application such as Illustrator or Photoshop.

There's no direct object-level editing really within Acrobat itself. Acrobat relies on other Adobe applications to edit anything beyond live type within a PDF.

Disclaimer: I'm not 100% current here with Acrobat DC. It's possible additional features have been recently added, although from my experience - direct object-level editing has never been a focus of the Acrobat dev team.